# Setting up internal Bluetooth card on Linux 2.6.38

Tags: kernel, linux-mint, bluetooth

I have a laptop that has a Bluetooth card in it, a Gateway NV series one. I'm trying to get it to turn on, as it currently isn't. The first time I booted after I wiped my drive and installed Linux Mint 11 from scratch, I saw the bluetooth light come on for the first time ever. However, it wasn't working, and after a reboot, it's no longer on.

Running `hcitool dev` only lists my USB dongle, or nothing if the dongle isn't plugged in. I've heard that there are kernel-level things I can do to fix this, where should I look for that? Is there a way for me to at least determine what kind of Bluetooth card I have in here so I can work on getting it working? `lsusb` doesn't give me anything relevant to Bluetooth:

```
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b044 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Acer CrystalEye Webcam
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 18d1:4e12 Google Inc. Nexus One Phone (Debug)
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0bc2:3001 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c526 Logitech, Inc. Nano Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 TERMINUS TECHNOLOGY INC. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Nor does `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ICH9M/M-E SATA AHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100
```

One thing's for sure, the card at the very least *turned on* the first time I booted, and something changed, preventing it from coming on. How can I determine what kind of card I have and how to enable it?

Comment: Double check your BIOS options and make sure anything that says "Bluetooth" is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange.  On my work Dell E6510 the bluetooth shows up as an "internal" USB device (visible with lspci) and I have no problems with it.

Try to see if you can get to the Gateway site where it allows you to download the Windows driver, and see if that tells you what kind of chipset/etc. it might be.  Otherwise you might have to take the back cover off and physically look at the chip.

Comment: Here's the page, not giving any details on Bluetooth: http://bit.ly/k4cLi1 . Booting to BIOS isn't as easy as it should be on this thing, let me give it a try in the morning. Thanks for the point in the right direction, I'll look into it and report back!

Comment: No luck there, unfortunately, nothing in the BIOS whatsoever about Bluetooth. Any other ideas?

Comment: I really don't know if this thing even has a Bluetooth card in it. Weird.